# Looking for open data on County Court Judgement against business in the UK

Tags: uk, companies

In the UK, as part of due diligence on companies, one typically looks on whether a company has received a County Court Judgement (CCJ). The Companies House website allows to retrieve lots of information on UK companies, but not the CCJ. Anybody knows if CCJ data at company level is available for free?